# Text Wrapping in Button Content in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I'm dynamically creating buttons in a page and some content may be longer than others. Buttons have equal sizes so I'd want the content, which is just plain text, to be wrapped. How do I do that?

Comment: Are you still experiencing any issues?

Answer (score 6):

In line with the link provided by Vap0r, here is a more specific answer to the original question concerning dynamically created buttons:

```
Button bt = new Button();
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "Text to be wrapped";
tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
bt.Content = tb;
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/124823.aspx) will help you.
It pretty much instructs you to open up your button tag and make your text inside a textblock wrap.